# Slow Build Times in .NET Core 3.1 and 5.0

Tags: performance, .net-core, build, nullable

I've noticed that the build time is exponentially slower in my new .NET Core project than in previous projects written in .NET Standard 4.  I tried a number of other solutions mentioned on here to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I had a "eureka" moment and finally tracked down the problem to having enabled nullable reference types in the project (.csproj) file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Stage</Configurations>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I didn't want to disable the feature but I also don't need my build times taking minutes instead of seconds.  To workaround this issue, I added a condition to my .csproj file to set nullability to false when performing a debug build inside Visual Studio:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Stage</Configurations>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- Disable nullable checks on debug build (fixes slow build issue) -->
<Target Name="DisableNullableForVisualStudioBuild"
        BeforeTargets="CoreCompile"
        Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'True' And '$(BuildingProject)' == 'True' And '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

Voila, problem solved!  This of course does have the unfortunate side effect of not having the compiler provide me warnings inside the Output panel regarding nullables, but I still get Intellisense warnings in real-time, so for me it's an acceptable compromise.